# Formatting quite a large amount of properties in view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor View with data passed in through the ViewBag (I cannot use a ViewModel). There are around 50 distinct properties passed through, each of which require their own conditional pre-formatting (some more than others.)

I can't decide where to format these values before displaying them. If formatting happens directly in the view, there will be **a lot** of if-else statement clogging up the view which, in my opinion, is a bit messy. The way I'm doing it at the moment is to pass in a list of pre-formatted (**done in the controller**) custom Property objects which the view iterates over using a @Helper method.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: Can't you create a ViewModel and pass that to the ViewBag (since you can't use a ViewModel directly)?

Comment: I was going to suggest what @Thijs did. Additionally, I would move the formatting logic to the model itself and expose properties that return the formatted values instead of the non-formatted ones, in case you will not use them anyway.

Comment: @Thijs that's a good shout actually. Veverke do you mean move the formatting logic to the ViewModel?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use a ViewModel?

Comment: @dav_i For this project, the ViewModel has been restricted for use only by a form.

Comment: @Titus: yep..........

Comment: @Veverke Yeah I think that's a good way to go, will see if this is possible within this project.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and reputation-whoring I added my solution below.

Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        set;
        get
        {
            return String.Format(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        var myModel = new MyModel();
        // Set properties
        ViewBag.ActualViewModel = myModel
        return View()
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
    var actualModel = ViewBag.ActualModel as MyModel;
}
```

Comment: I think it sums up what the directions you received :-)

Comment: @Veverke, I will upvote a usefull awnser you have given to share the karma ;)

Comment: SO just turned into real business... =]